# Users are able to become root using "sudo sudo su -"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, sudo, centos-7

I have given below permissions in sudoers file.

```
Cmnd_Alias      SUROOT=/bin/su "",\
                       /bin/su -,\
                       /bin/su - root,\
                       /bin/su root,\
                       /usr/bin/su "",\
                       /usr/bin/su -,\
                       /usr/bin/su - root,\
                       /usr/bin/su root
kj ALL = (ALL) ALL, !SUROOT
```

when I try to access `sudo su -` its blocked

```
kj@u1804-1:~$ sudo su -
[sudo] password for kj:
Sorry, user kj is not allowed to execute '/bin/su -' as root on u1804-1.
```

But when I try to access `sudo sudo su -` it allows.

```
kj@u1804-1:~$ sudo sudo su -
[sudo] password for kj:
root@u1804-1:~#
```

I need to block access to root user how can I block `sudo sudo` command

Comment: Does adding to the list `sudo sudo su -` help?

Comment: no I tried it. it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot achieve this by blocking individual commands. There are dozens, if not *hundreds*, of commands that people can use to become root through `sudo`:

```
sudo -s
sudo -i
sudo bash
sudo env su
sudo /bin/sh
sudo env sudo
sudo busybox sh
sudo unshare
sudo chroot /
sudo systemd-run --shell
sudo nvim -c ":terminal"
sudo perl -e 'exec("bash")'
sudo git -c protocol.ext.allow=always ls-remote ext::"bash -c sh<&2>&2"
```

They could rename the blocked commands:

```
sudo cp -a /sbin/su /sbin/really-not-su && sudo really-not-su
```

They could simply change the rules you've set:

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
```

Hopefully the point has been made – if you're giving people root access, **you are giving them root access.** The only option is to have a list of *allowed* commands and block everything else – and even then, half of those commands will have a way to gain full root access.

(AppArmor or SELinux may help here.)

Comment: Hi Grawity, Thanks for the inputs. I get the point, there are multiple ways to do it. But for my use case I want to block sudo sudo su. I am ok to restrict using PAM or other options as well. This is tough that we have multiple ways to misuse sudo to get elavated access.

Comment: That's not misuse. Elevated access is the whole point of sudo.

Comment: What will be the best way to restrict or limit Elevated access then.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest perhaps the opposite approach : Rather than give some persons unlimited
root permissions, to allow them to execute some commands as `sudo` and without
specifying the password. This would allow them to execute the operations
they need to do, but no more than that.

The `sudoers` file can even define the allowed parameters on the command(s),
also with wildcards for allowing the inclusion of strings in the command.

This approach is best described in an answer from the Unix Stackexchange post
[How to remote execute ssh command a sudo command without password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395776/how-to-remote-execute-ssh-command-a-sudo-command-without-password).

> you can tell sudo to skip password for some command.
>
> e.g. in `/etc/sudoers`
>
> ```
> archemar  ALL = (www-data) NOPASSWD: /bin/rm -rf /var/www/log/upload.*
> ```
>
> this allow me to use
>
> ```
> sudo -u www-data /bin/rm -rf /var/www/log/upload.*
> ```
>
> as archemar without password.
>
> Note that
>
> ```
> sudo -u www-data rm -rf /var/www/log/upload.*
> ```
>
> won't work (will ask a password) as `rm` differ from `/bin/rm`.
>
> Be sure to edit `/etc/sudoers` using `visudo` command.
>
> Once you've reach advanced level, you might wish to have your own
>   `sudo` files in `/etc/sudoers.d`.